# Linux (ubuntu). SVN + TRAC. Displaying SVN project in TRAC

Tags: svn, ubuntu, trac

I have already installed trac + svn (Linux Ubuntu).
It is necessary that a TRAC could see a list of files in the SVN repository.

In localhost/trac/browser/ I see the error:

```
"Unsupported version control system "svn": libneon-gnutls.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Did you check trac wiki already? http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#unsupported-vcs

Answer (score 3):

It's a common mistake, but there are two different Python bindings for subversion libraries. The one that Trac needs for its Subversion integration is in the `python-subversion` Ubuntu package, **NOT** the `python-svn` package, so you **need to install the `python-subversion` package** (see [Trac and Subversion](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#TracandSubversion)).